# Check if bit is set in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a field which stores the days of the week in binary representation. For example, Mon-Wed-Fri would be represented as b'0101010' with the 1st digit as Sunday and the last as Saturday.

What I want to achieve: If today is Monday, I want to check if the Monday bit is set to 1. I do that by doing (b'0101010' & b'0100000' > 0). But I am struggling in converting the current date into the corresponding weekday binary representation. How can I achieve so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following expression will give the bit representation of today's day of week:

```
POW(2, 7 - DAYOFWEEK(NOW())
```

- `POW(2, n)` raises 2 to the nth power, which is the same as shifting 1 n bits from the right.
- `DAYOFWEEK(date)` returns the day of the week as a number, with Sunday = 1.
- Since you have the low-numbered dates in the high-order bits, `7 - DOW` converts that to Sunday = 6, Saturday = 0.

Wouldn't it be easier to declare the column as a `SET`, though? Then you could just use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: I was not aware of this column SET. Also your formula works!

Comment: Sets are implemented as bit masks just like you're doing, but MySQL takes care of translating to and from strings for programming ease.

Comment: If I use SET, would I need 1 column per bit?

Comment: No, it's just like you're doing. Read the [documentation of mysql SET datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html)